# What is meant by linearity of a dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know what is meant by linearity of a dot product.

Thank you

Comment: More precisely, the dot product is *bilinear*, which means that it is linear in both of its variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the dot product satisfies two properties:

- If $u$, $v$ and $w$ are vectors such that $\cdot$ and $+$ make sense, $$u \cdot (v + w) = u \cdot v + u \cdot w$$ and vice-versa:
  $$(u + v) \cdot w = u \cdot w + v \cdot w$$
- If $u$ and $v$ are vectors such that $\cdot$ makes sense, and $c$ is a scalar, $$(cu) \cdot v = c (u \cdot v)$$ and vice-versa: $$u \cdot (cv) = c (u \cdot v)$$

Answer (score 4):

For a scalar $c$ and vectors $v,w,u$, 
$$
(c\, v+w)\cdot u=c(v\cdot u)+w\cdot u, \ \ u\cdot(c\,v+w)=c\,(u\cdot v)+u\cdot w.
$$
In other words, the dot product is linear in each of its two variables.